# How to change elasticsearch status from yellow to green?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm having only one node, I set the replica to 0 and shards to 1 by using below script:

```
PUT /my_temp_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards" :   1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

output:

```
{
   "cluster_name": "KMT",
   "status": "yellow",
   "timed_out": false,
   "number_of_nodes": 1,
   "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
   "active_primary_shards": 452,
   "active_shards": 452,
   "relocating_shards": 0,
   "initializing_shards": 0,
   "unassigned_shards": 451,
   "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
   "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
   "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
   "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
   "active_shards_percent_as_number": 50.055370985603545
}
```

should I have to restart elasticsearch after the changes?

Comment: please provide index details using GET /_stats.

Comment: @BlackPOP after applying GET /_stats i am getting 21667 lines message as output.

Comment: @raam86 dude, i just want to change the status yellow to green. after applying i got the "acknowledgement true" message as output.

Comment: Cluster status is dependent on all index, so i think some of the other index shards are not being allocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only changed the number of replicas for a single index + the property names are wrong (missing the `index.` prefix).

You need to run the same query on all indices instead

```
PUT /*/_settings
{
    "index": {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Comment: i am getting "reason": "Invalid index name [_all], must not start with '_', '-', or '+'", in output

Comment: My bad, it's `*` and not `_all`, please see my updated answer and try again.

Comment: index is not needed?

Comment: See that I'm now using the `_settings` endpoint directly and the `index` prefix moved up one level.

Comment: Now i am getting this messge   "reason": "Can't update [index.number_of_replicas] on closed indices [[logstash-KMT-2017.04.12/8wd8dbRjRxer8vHWMGmDgg]] - can leave index in an unopenable state"

Comment: Of course all your indexes need to be opened, which is not the case for `logstash-KMT-2017.04.12`.

Comment: Awesome, glad we figured it out.